# Basic function theory notation: $f_n$, $f^n$ and $f(n)$

Tags: functions, notation, fixed-point-theorems

Im trying to learn some concepts by reading notation, but I need to know if I understand it correctly.

I read that one could use the index notation $f_n$ instead of $f(n)$, is that right? [Wikipage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)#Index_notation) say that $f_n$ is called the n'th element of the sequence in $f(n)$ (typically when the the domain is the set of the natural numbers).

But $n$ in $f(n)$ doesnt necessarily mean the same? It's a placeholder for a number in a function like for example:
$$f(n) = 2^n$$
And
$$f_n = 2^n$$
just does not seem right to me. But is it valid and/or common?

If we define $f^n$ as the n'th iterate, then I can agree that in a sequence $n$ is the n'th element. So from the above statement taken from the wikipage, is the n'th element the same as the n'th iterate? But both of them are defined differently: $f^n$ and $f_n$?

However I am confused by the notation, because there are three ways to note:

$f^n$, $f_n$ and $f(n)$.

Please, I am interested in learning more about Iterated Function Theory and know the difference between [pointwise convergence/local uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_convergence) and [uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence). But before that, I need to understand this basic theory of functions and notation.

Since I am interested in sequences in iterated functions, I want to be able to describe how n'th element, m'th iterate and so on is notated.

I have not found one good example online that explains their differences concretely. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

$f^n$ is usually used to mean the $n$th power of $f,$ rather than the $n$th iterate:$$f^n(x)= \overbrace{f(x)f(x)\dots f(x)}^{n \text{ factors}}$$  When it means the $n$th iterate, the author will typically say so.

You can usually count on $f(n)$'s meaning the value of the function $f$ at $n$.
$f_n$ could mean $f(n),$ particularly when the domain is the natural numbers, but more usually it means the $n$th function in a sequence of functions.

Still, there aren't any hard-and-fast rules.  You have to determine the meaning from the context -- just like reading anything else.

Comment: Ok, I see. There is also $f(f(f(n)))$... etc. which I want to note as $f_3$. or $f(f(f(...))$ n-times defined as $f_n$. How do I specify that in an iterated function, because this is confusing. Do I have to read alot of papers to see how they specify and define functions?

Comment: Depending on the context, $f^3(n)$ (for instance) could mean $(f(n))^3$ or $f(f(f(n)))$. There is no universal notation for that. I mean, If you are writing a paper, you just need to say what a notation means and then you can use it as you please.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy Yes, that's what I mean by the $n$th iterate.  You don't have to read a lot of papers; you have to read each paper carefully.